# Why I cannot use extern like this?

Tags: c++

I want to change `g` value in main function.Then use `func()`.The `func()` will calculate a value base on `g` value.If `g` changed the result of `func()` will change. 
I have writte some code but ut complier is giving error, can someone help me fix this?

main.cpp

[image]

test.cpp

[image]

errors

[image]

Comment: The error is #include "test.cpp", don't do it!

Comment: Don't post pictures. Your IDE has a perfectly functional "Copy" operation.

Comment: C++ code consists of plain text, plain text is easy to copy & paste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to your errant `#include "test.cpp"`, the function `func` is compiled in more than one compilation unit.

The linker will object to that.

Normally, you only include header files using `#include`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your main.cpp. You shouldn't include .cpp files because of the preprocessor :

The content of test.cpp is copied top of your main.cpp file. So when your compiler goes right after it, it'll have the declaration of void func() in your main.cpp AND in test.cpp, resulting of multiply defined symbols.

Remove your #include "test.cpp", add an extern reference to your 'void func();' in main.cpp or declare the prototype in a test.h header.

Answer (score 1):

***You must not include test.cpp.***

Otherwise it is compiled twice.

1. It is compiled as a file in its own belonging to the project.
2. It is compiled when it is included

And when the link occurs, it tells the function exists twice

***The answer is :***

1. Create test.h

Put inside the prototype of func :

```
// It is a prototype, no implementation but a ;
void func();
```

2. include `test.h` in `main.cpp`

```
 #include "test.h"
```

Regards